# object of type '_Task' has no len() error

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am using the parallel programming module for python I have a function that returns me an array but when I print the variable that contain the value of the function parallelized returns me "pp._Task object at 0x04696510" and not the value of the matrix.
Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import scipy, pylab
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import sys
import peakpicker as pea
import pp
import fingerprint as fhash
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import tdft
import subprocess
import time
if __name__ == '__main__':
        start=time.time()
        #Peak picking dimensions 
        f_dim1 = 30
        t_dim1 = 80 
        f_dim2 = 10
        t_dim2 = 20
        percentile = 80
        base = 100 # lowest frequency bin used (peaks below are too common/not as useful for identification)
        high_peak_threshold = 75
        low_peak_threshold = 60
        #TDFT parameters
        windowsize = 0.008     #set the window size  (0.008s = 64 samples)
        windowshift = 0.004    #set the window shift (0.004s = 32 samples)
        fftsize = 1024         #set the fft size (if srate = 8000, 1024 --> 513 freq. bins separated by 7.797 Hz from 0 to 4000Hz) 

        #Hash parameters
        delay_time = 250     # 250*0.004 = 1 second#200
        delta_time = 250*3    # 750*0.004 = 3 seconds#300
        delta_freq = 128      # 128*7.797Hz = approx 1000Hz#80
        #Time pair parameters
        TPdelta_freq = 4
        TPdelta_time = 2


        #Cargando datos almacenados
        database=np.loadtxt('database.dat')
        songnames=np.loadtxt('songnames.dat', dtype=str, delimiter='\t')
        separator = '.'
        print('Please enter an audio sample file to identify: ')
        userinput = raw_input('---> ')
        subprocess.call(['ffmpeg','-y','-i',userinput, '-ac', '1','-ar', '8k', 'filesample.wav'])   
        sample = read('filesample.wav')
        userinput = userinput.split(separator,1)[0]
        print('Analyzing the audio sample: '+str(userinput))
        srate = sample[0]  #sample rate in samples/second
        audio = sample[1]  #audio data      
        spectrogram = tdft.tdft(audio, srate, windowsize, windowshift, fftsize)
        mytime = spectrogram.shape[0]
        freq = spectrogram.shape[1]

        print('The size of the spectrogram is time: '+str(mytime)+' and freq: '+str(freq))

        threshold = pea.find_thres(spectrogram, percentile, base)

        peaks = pea.peak_pick(spectrogram,f_dim1,t_dim1,f_dim2,t_dim2,threshold,base)

        print('The initial number of peaks is:'+str(len(peaks)))
        peaks = pea.reduce_peaks(peaks, fftsize, high_peak_threshold, low_peak_threshold)
        print('The reduced number of peaks is:'+str(len(peaks)))

        #Store information for the spectrogram graph
        samplePeaks = peaks
        sampleSpectro = spectrogram

        hashSample = fhash.hashSamplePeaks(peaks,delay_time,delta_time,delta_freq)
        print('The dimensions of the hash matrix of the sample: '+str(hashSample.shape))


        # tuple of all parallel python servers to connect with
        ppservers = ()
        #ppservers = ("10.0.0.1",)

        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            ncpus = int(sys.argv[1])
            # Creates jobserver with ncpus workers
            job_server = pp.Server(ncpus, ppservers=ppservers)
        else:
            # Creates jobserver with automatically detected number of workers
            job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=ppservers)

        print ("Starting pp with", job_server.get_ncpus(), "workers")

        print('Attempting to identify the sample audio clip.')
```

Here I call the function in fingerprint, the commented line worked, but when I try parallelize don't work:

```
        timepairs = job_server.submit(fhash.findTimePairs, (database, hashSample, TPdelta_freq, TPdelta_time, ))
#        timepairs = fhash.findTimePairs(database, hashSample, TPdelta_freq, TPdelta_time)
        print (timepairs)


        #Compute number of matches by song id to determine a match
        numSongs = len(songnames)
        songbins= np.zeros(numSongs)
        numOffsets = len(timepairs)
        offsets = np.zeros(numOffsets)
        index = 0
        for i in timepairs:
                offsets[index]=i[0]-i[1]
                index = index+1
                songbins[i[2]] += 1

        # Identify the song
        #orderarray=np.column_stack((songbins,songnames))
        #orderarray=orderarray[np.lexsort((songnames,songbins))]
        q3=np.percentile(songbins, 75)
        q1=np.percentile(songbins, 25)
        j=0
        for i in songbins:
                if i>(q3+(3*(q3-q1))):
                        print("Result-> "+str(i)+":"+songnames[j])
                j+=1
        end=time.time()
        print('Tiempo: '+str(end-start)+' s')
        print("Time elapsed: ", +time.time() - start, "s")
        fig3 = pylab.figure(1003)
        ax = fig3.add_subplot(111)
        ind = np.arange(numSongs)
        width = 0.35
        rects1 = ax.bar(ind,songbins,width,color='blue',align='center')
        ax.set_ylabel('Number of Matches')
        ax.set_xticks(ind)
        xtickNames = ax.set_xticklabels(songnames)
        matplotlib.pyplot.setp(xtickNames)
        pylab.title('Song Identification') 
        fig3.show()

        pylab.show()

        print('The sample song is: '+str(songnames[np.argmax(songbins)]))
```

The function in fingerprint that I try to parallelize is:

```
def findTimePairs(hash_database,sample_hash,deltaTime,deltaFreq):
"Find the matching pairs between sample audio file and the songs in the database"

timePairs = []

for i in sample_hash:
    for j in hash_database:
        if(i[0] > (j[0]-deltaFreq) and i[0] < (j[0] + deltaFreq)):
            if(i[1] > (j[1]-deltaFreq) and i[1] < (j[1] + deltaFreq)):
                if(i[2] > (j[2]-deltaTime) and i[2] < (j[2] + deltaTime)):
                    timePairs.append((j[3],i[3],j[4]))
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue

return timePairs
```

The complete error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "analisisPrueba.py", line 93, in <module>
numOffsets = len(timepairs)
TypeError: object of type '_Task' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `submit()` method submits a task to the server. What you get back is a reference to the task, not its result. (How could it return its result? `submit()` returns before any of that work has been done!) You should instead provide a callback function to receive the results. For example, `timepairs.append` is a function that will take the result and append it to the list `timepairs`.

```
timepairs = []
job_server.submit(fhash.findTimePairs, (database, hashSample, TPdelta_freq, TPdelta_time, ), callback=timepairs.append)
```

(Each `findTimePairs` call should calculate *one* result, in case that isn't obvious, and you should submit *multiple* tasks. Otherwise you're invoking all the machinery of Parallel Python for no reason. And make sure you call `job_server.wait()` to wait for all the tasks to finish before trying to do anything with your results. In short, read the documentation and some example scripts and make sure you understand how it works.)

Comment: I pretend submit multiple tasks with different database but it was first tested. I tried your code but not stored anything in timepairs. On http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/17/31/ there are some instances in which I relied.

Comment: I found the solution, I called timepairs as a function.                               job1 = timepairs()